# Communication between scripts in Firefox addon sdk - self.port doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to make a firefox addon using their sdk, but I don't know how to make my js scripts communicate. The goal is to make a panel with a form in witch there are 3 checkboxes that when selected can hide/show certain elements on the active tab.

Here are the scripts:
main.js:

```
var data = require("sdk/self").data;

var painel1 = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 215,
    height: 160,
    contentURL: data.url("painelDestroyer.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery.js"),data.url("panel.js")]
});

require("sdk/widget").Widget({
    id: "open-form-btn",
    label: "Clear",
    contentURL: data.url("mozico.png"),
    panel: painel1
});

// Attach a content script to the current active tab
let worker = require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("clear.js")
});


painel1.port.on("show-tag",function(tag){
    worker.port.emit("show-tag", {tag:tag});
    console.log("worker emited");
});

painel1.port.on("hide-tag",function(tag){
    worker.port.emit("clear-tag", {tag:tag});
    console.log("worker emited");
});
```

painel.js:

```
$("#imgD").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        panel.port.emit("clear-tag","img");
        console.log("panel emited");
    } else {
       panel.port.emit("show-tag","img");
       console.log("panel emited");
    }
});
$("#aD").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        panel.port.emit("clear-tag","a");
        console.log("panel emited");
    } else {
        panel.port.emit("show-tag","a");
        console.log("panel emited");
    }
});
$("#iframeD").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       panel.port.emit("clear-tag","iframe");
       console.log("panel emited");
    } else {
        panel.port.emit("show-tag","iframe");
        console.log("panel emited");
    }
});
```

clear.js:

```
    function tagHide (tag, hide) {
    $(tag).each(function() {
        if (hide === false) {
            $(this).css({
                "visibility": "visible"
            });
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
            });
        }
    });
}

self.port.on('show-tag', function(tag) {
    tagHide(tag, false);
});
self.port.on('clear-tag', function(tag) {
    tagHide(tag, true);
});
```

Question: How do I make this work, how to comunicated between this 3 scripts? My guess is that I have to send a message from the painel.js to main.js and then to the clean.js, but how do I do that? How do I receive a message in clean.js or painel.js?
I keep getting that self.port doesn't exist in painel.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to access and modify the content of a page from a *module script* instead of a *content script*. There's no `window` or `document` in the scope of a module script, as explained in [the documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/dev-guide/guides/two-types-of-scripts.html). As such, jQuery's `$` won't have anything to work with in your add-on script.

You need to [`attach`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/modules/sdk/tabs.html#attach%28options%29) another content script to the current tab. You can then show/hide elements on the page by sending messages to its worker port, similar to how you communicate between your add-on module script and your panel script.

```
// Attach a content script to the current active tab
let worker = require("sdk/tabs").activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: data.url("tabscript.js")
});
// Send it a message
worker.port.emit("show-tag", tag);
```

You would then move your `tagHide` function to that content script for the active tab and put some port listeners in there. That way, the add-on script can emit some messages and have the content script call `tagHide` appropriately.

**Note:** You're probably better off using a `page-mod` rather than attaching to a tab. In the end, you probably don't want to manually attach your script every time the user navigates to a different page, so a global PageMod (`include: "*"`) is an easy solution. Still, you'll need to make sure you're targeting the worker *of the current tab* when forwarding your messages. Therefore, you'll need to keep track of all those workers and [clean them up when the worker is detached](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/modules/sdk/page-mod.html#Destroying%20Workers) (using `worker.on('detach', callback)`. Finally, you should iterate over all currently attached workers and find the worker attached to the page of the currently active tab (by comparing each `worker.tab` to `tabs.activeTab`).

Alternatively, you could simply inject the commands straight into the tab page as JavaScript as shown in [Attaching Content Scripts to Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/modules/sdk/page-mod.html#Attaching%20Content%20Scripts%20to%20Tabs). I find this quite ugly and it doesn't allow you to retain some state in the content script (variables on a page retained across commands) which you might need for more complex scripts.

**UPDATE 1**: As for your updated question, the answer is [very well documented in the SDK guides](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html#Accessing%20port%20in%20the%20Content%20Script). You just need to bind a listener using `self.port.on`:

```
self.port.on('show-tag', function(tag) {
    tagHide(tag, false);
});
self.port.on('clear-tag', function(tag) {
    tagHide(tag);
});
```

On another note, your current code only ever works with the currently active tab *when the add-on starts*. Most likely, the active tab changes and you'll need to inject your content script into other tabs over time. See my previous note on how you *could* manage the workers of all these scripts.

Comment: But then how do I do to switch between "show-tag" and "hide-tag", since it is defined by the js in the panel?
Would I have to add a port.emiter in the pannel.js file to the add-on script and then to the content script? As in emit "1" or "2" from the panel to the add-on script and then resend it to the content script to take action on the page? Cause I need to use the panel script to decide if its a "1" or "2" (in this case "show" or "hide").

Comment: Yes, you'll need to make your add-on script "forward" the command from the panel's content script to the tab's content script. For example, in the [Annotator tutorial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/dev-guide/tutorials/annotator/overview.html) a `left-click` from the widget content script is forwarded by `main.js` to an `activate/deactivate` message on the `page-mod` content script.

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro Yes, `self.port.on` should "just work" inside a content script (on a panel or a page). You don't need to `require` anything, `self` should just be available as a global variable.

Comment: Its not working some how, it gives me that self.port is not defined.

Comment: it seems like self.port.on is depreciated. Any idea on how to do that now? I can't find anything